# Mac Sandboxing: Can it really be this easy?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm just trying to get some confirmation on Sandboxing. I understand exactly why it's been put in place and the principle behind it.

As I start to near the release of my first Mac App I kept putting off sandboxing as it sounded rather complicated and thought I'll worry about it nearer the time. I watched a couple of the Apple videos and read up on some of the documentation (not all) and thought I'd try and add it to my app!

I turned on sandboxing in Xcode, didn't specify any entitlements as they didn't really relate to my app and the entitlements certificate popped up on the left and ran my app....that was it, all ran fine without issues.

That's where I got confused...surely it can't be that simple?! My app saves data in the background, no user input to save, it just happens seamlessly. Anyway I checked /Users/whoever/Library/Containers and there was my app named container folder and the relevant data was saved there (although of course that wasn't the exact path I specified as the save location in my app). I closed my app, reopened it and sure enough the saved data was still there.

IS THAT IT? Does that now mean my app is sandboxed or am I missing something here?

Comment: Why is this tagged "osx-snow-leopard"? There is no sandbox on Snow Leopard, and there's no way anything would get created under ~/Library/Containers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's it. If your app really doesn't need any entitlements, not even the ability to open/save files specified by the user, then it's trivial to sandbox.